# For loop with function in Python -Code not running with list but running in standalone

Tags: python, function, dataframe, for-loop, arguments

def predict_movies(mnames) was working perfecting and giving the output data frame. But when tried to pass the input argument as a list of mnames it was giving output. It is also not throwing error. Looks like iam doing a trivial error. The same code for a single input argument is working perfectly well. THe elements of the input list are available in all the relevant files pointed in the function.Your help is appreciated.
Codeblocks as below.

```
movie_names_for_predictions=['Return of the Jedi (1983)','Wrong Trousers, The (1993)','Pink Floyd - The Wall (1982)','North by Northwest (1959)']

for mnames in range(0,len(movie_names_for_predictions)):
       
        def predict_movies(mnames):
                movie_user_ratings=movieRatings[mnames]
                similar_to_movie=movieRatings.corrwith(movie_user_ratings)
                corr_movie=pd.DataFrame(similar_to_movie,columns=['correlation'])
                corr_movie.dropna(inplace=True)
                corr_movie=corr_movie.join(ratings_compiled['Number of ratings'])
                predictions=corr_movie[corr_movie['Number of ratings']>100].sort_values('correlation',ascending=False)
                return print(mnames,predictions)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redeclare your function every time in the loop which is unnecessary. You could declare your function before running the loop and call it in each iteration.

```py
def predict_movies(mname):
    movie_user_ratings = movieRatings[mname]
    similar_to_movie = movieRatings.corrwith(movie_user_ratings)
    corr_movie = pd.DataFrame(similar_to_movie, columns=['correlation'])
    corr_movie.dropna(inplace=True)
    corr_movie = corr_movie.join(ratings_compiled['Number of ratings'])
    predictions = corr_movie[corr_movie['Number of ratings'] > 100].sort_values('correlation', ascending=False)
    # Don't return a print statement
    return predictions

movie_names_for_predictions = ['Return of the Jedi (1983)', 'Wrong Trousers, The (1993)', 'Pink Floyd - The Wall (1982)', 'North by Northwest (1959)']

# Less boilerplate code for looping
for mname in movie_names_for_predictions:
    predictions = predict_movies(mname)
    print(mname, predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting me and clear explanation with comments.                      
   It was a silly mistake i was doing.